# Positioning of text under a div that is absolute

Tags: css

I currently have something like this

```html
<div class="mycol" id="mycanvas" style="z-index: -1; top:150px;left:240px;width:88%; height:80%; position: absolute;background-color:red;">
</div>

<div class="testclass">
  Hello World
</div>
```

I would like the content of `testclass` to appear below `mycol` class. I know i could do that by making it absolute is there any where other than that by which i can tell it to vertically start of when the `mycol` class ends

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `testclass` inside `mycol`, and add `position: relative; top: 100%;` to `testclass` like this:

```html
<div class="mycol" id="mycanvas" style="z-index: -1; top: 150px; left: 240px; width: 88%; height: 80%; position: absolute; background-color: red;">
  <div class="testclass" style="position: relative; top: 100%;">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement of keeping the div.testclass under `div.mycol` doesn't need the use of position.

If you can explain the complete requirement which you are trying to achive can help all to give you a better solution.

```html
<div style="height:200px;padding:50px;">
  <div class="mycol" id="mycanvas" style="width:88%; height:80%;background-color:red;">
  </div>

  <div class="testclass" style="margin-top:20px;">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, by making `mycol` have `position:aboslute` you are removing it from the page's normal flow. We can demonstrate this like so.

```
<div class="mycol" style="position: absolute; height: 80%; width: 88%; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4); top: 150px; left: 240px;">
</div>

<div class="testclass" style="margin-left: 500px; height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: black;"></div>
```

As you can see, the `testclass` is completely unaffected by `mycol`'s position.

So, in your sample, although we can see the red box, it is not affecting the position of "Hello World".

If we would like to move the text below it, then we could use margins, disrupt the normal flow (using position), or put content behind the existing text to eventually force it below it.

Since you specified that you do not want to use the position technique, then I will demonstrate this using margins. We can use percents, such as : `margin-top: 80%`, but this would have some odd effects. W3 specifics that margin-top goes off of the width of it's container when using percents, so you wouldn't benefit a whole lot.

Regardless, it does answer your question!

```
<div class="mycol" style="position: absolute; height: 80%; width: 88%; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4); top: 150px; left: 240px;">
</div>


<div class="testclass" style="margin-top:100%; background-color: gray;">
    Hello world
</div>
```